# How to fix rust-lld error SBREL relocation to xxx without static base with rwpi relocation model?

Tags: rust, embedded, cortex-m, lld

For research purpose, I'm trying to build an image for my cortex-m4 microcontroller with `rwpi` relocation model. However, during linking stage, lld throws me the error:

```
rust-lld: error: SBREL relocation to __sbss without static base
```

Below is an easy way to reproduce this error. This follows the tutorial in [The Embedded Rust Book](https://docs.rust-embedded.org/book/start/qemu.html).

1. `cargo install cargo-generate` to install an handy tool.
2. `cargo generate --git https://github.com/rust-embedded/cortex-m-quickstart` to download the example code.
3. `cd` into the cloned directory. Modify `.cargo/config`. Add `"-C", "relocation-model=rwpi"` to `rustflags`.
4. Run `cargo build`.

The example code in `main.rs` uses the `cortex-m-rt` crate, which during compile time will generate a link script for the linker. The generated link script can be found at `./target/thumbv7m-none-eabi/debug/build/cortex-m-rt-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/out/link.x`. I suppose that some information is missing for the linker. What should I do to resolve the issue?

Comment: Found any solution ?

Comment: @PinkTurtle I gave up directly using `cortex-m-rt` and wrote my own bootstrap code by studying this crate. The problem originated from the declaration of the `__sbss` variable in `cortex-m-rt`. I remember they declare it as `extern "C" { static __sbss: &u32; }` or something similar. Declare it as `extern "C" { static __sbss: u32; }` can resolve it. (Remove `&`) Though theoretically we should place `&` there. It works, but sincerely I don't know why.

Comment: It turns out my problem was "Initialized globals are unfortunately not supported." (writing a Ledger embedded app). Maybe that was your issue?

Comment: @PinkTurtle I have no idea on this... Hope you can figure out a solution soon

Comment: yes I did. Just had to initialize globals through an init function.